# Primefaces dataTable edit nullPointerException

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I currently have a dataTable connecting to a database. It all worked fine including insert and delete. I then tried to add editing into my dataTable and all of a sudden I get the following error:

> SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [FacesServlet] in context with path [/ProEJT] threw exception [null] with root cause
>   java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at org.primefaces.component.celleditor.CellEditorRenderer.encodeEnd(CellEditorRenderer.java:38)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeCell(DataTableRenderer.java:823)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRow(DataTableRenderer.java:784)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRows(DataTableRenderer.java:699)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:654)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:249)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:211)
>       at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:83)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
>       at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1779)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
>       at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:437)
>       at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:124)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>       at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>       at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

As far as I can tell, this does not tell me where the NullPointerException comes from in my code. I have tried what feels like a million different things with no luck.

My dataTable:

```
        <h:form id="form1">
        <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" life="3000"/>
        <p:dataTable id="dataTable" 
                    var="order" 
                    value="#{checkOut.orders}" 
                    ajax="true"
                    paginator="true" 
                    selection="#{checkOut.selectedOrder}"
                    selectionMode="single"
                    rowKey="#{order.id}" 
                    rows="10"  
                    sortMode="Multiple"
                    paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
                    emptymessage="No orders found"  
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" 
                    rowStyleClass="#{(order.state == 'ERROR' ? 'error' : (order.state == 'Finished' ? 'finished' : (order.state == 'Failed' ? 'failed':(order.state == 'Paused' ? 'paused' : null ))))}"
                    editable="true"
                    editMode="row">


                <f:facet name="header">
                    Conversions
                </f:facet>

            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{checkOut.onEdit}" update=":form:growl" />
            <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{checkOut.onCancel}" update=":form:growl"/>

            <p:column sortBy="#{order.id}">
                <p:cellEditor >
                    <f:facet name="Output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{order.id}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="Input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{order.id}" style="width:100%"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="#{order.created}" >
                <p:cellEditor >
                    <f:facet name="Output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{order.created}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="Input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{order.created}" style="width:100%"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="#{order.sender}" >
                <p:cellEditor >
                    <f:facet name="Output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{order.sender}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="Input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{order.sender}" style="width:100%"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="#{order.receiver}">
                <p:cellEditor >
                    <f:facet name="Output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{order.receiver}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="Input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{order.receiver}" style="width:100%"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="#{order.input}" >
                <p:cellEditor >
                    <f:facet name="Output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{order.input}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="Input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{order.input}" style="width:100%"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="#{order.output}">
                <p:cellEditor >
                    <f:facet name="Output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{order.output}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="Input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{order.output}" style="width:100%"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

            <p:column sortBy="#{order.state}">

                <p:cellEditor >
                    <f:facet name="Output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{order.state}"/>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="Input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{order.state}" style="width:100%"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
                <p:progressBar id="progressBarClient" value="#{checkOut.retrieveProgress(order.state)}" labelTemplate="{value}%" displayOnly="true"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column >
                <p:commandLink id="btnDeleteRow" action="#{checkOut.deleteRow(order)}" update="dataTable" ajax="true">
                    <h:graphicImage value="/img/DeleteRed.png" style="align:center" width="30" height="30"/>
                </p:commandLink>
                <p:rowEditor />
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
        <p:commandButton id="new" value="Create A New Order" update=":orderForm" oncomplete="newOrderDialog.show()" style="position:absolute; dataTable:10px; left:7px;"/>
        <p:commandButton id="logout" value="Log Out" update="growl" action="#{checkOut.logout}" style="position:absolute; dataTable:10px; right:10px"/>             
    </h:form>
```

Comment: Just have a look at [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableCellEditing.jsf) and find the difference with your code.

Comment: I used the Show Case row edit example to create the editing and have had another look through it and cannot see any differences

Comment: I don't think you did this code based in the showcase. I had a general look to it (for 30 secs) and saw an important difference which can cause the error. Just have a look to it and you'll notice. By the way, `dataTable` doesn't have `ajax` attribute as far as I know.

Comment: I have a suggestion for you. Instead of looking for differences, do a backup of the file you posted. Then copy-paste the showcase code and start adapting it to your code, till it works. You've a lot of mess in your table, just start from a basic one and add everything you need when it's working.

Comment: I did start from a basic one and added each little thing bit by bit and got each working before I started the next one. What mess are you talking about? Is there unnecessary elements to it or just a lot of things?

Comment: For these concrete problem, most of your `dataTable` attributes are unecessary (problem unrelated). You can also get rid of ajax events. You could take just one of your columns, as you don't need all the columns to replay the error, as it's related with all of them. Always you've to try to isolate the problem. In this case, as @Pushkar says it's only about a letter case ;-)

Comment: Normally I would have made the code specific to the error by deleting all the other things such as sorting but as the error did not tell me where the problem was, i did not know if these were related or not.

Comment: Just test by yourself deleting things till everything works properly! This helps you to find/isolate the problem. In case you isolate it, it's easier too for people here to watch what happens. You'll find [this site](http://sscce.org/) interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use input & output facet in small cases;

```
<f:facet name="output">
</f:facet>

<f:facet name="input">
</f:facet>
```

Comment: Thank you Pushkar. After changing that and re adding the ajax="true" into the datatable it now works.

Comment: Your most welcome DannyBoy .
@Xtreme Biker is correct, SSCCE in our practice is very important.

Comment: I have cross checked it but couldn't resolve it. There is any other settings?

Comment: @Sarz can you please provide more information what exactly you facing

Comment: I get the problem my tag were not balanced :( Because we are using template in web

Comment: @Sarz then i guess you need to check is all tag is closed correctly or not where need to get closed

Comment: Solved it!, BalusC is really helpful.

Comment: @Sarz he is master in JSF

Answer (score 1):

Yes sometimes is because is not the same example of the showcase, in my case use the same structure for my window.

```
<p:cellEditor>
    <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.id}" /></f:facet>
    <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{car.id}" style="width:96%"/></f:facet>
</p:cellEditor>
```

Comment: <p:cellEditor>
                  <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{car.id}" /></f:facet>
                  <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="modelInput" value="#{car.id}" style="width:96%"/></f:facet>
              </p:cellEditor>